Cannot find module 'primeng/floatlabel' or its corresponding type declarations in primeng 17
I use Primeng version 17 in my project.
Exactly according to the documentation, I went ahead and imported primeng/floatlabel and it gives an unrelated error

where is the problem from ?

The versions of my packages are as follows
"@angular/animations": "~17.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^17.2.0",
"@angular/common": "~17.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~17.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~17.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "~17.0.0",
"@angular/localize": "~17.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~17.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~17.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~17.0.0",
"primeicons": "^6.0.1",
"primeng": "^17.7.0",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"xlsx": "^0.18.5",
"zone.js": "~0.14.0"


Update to the latest version of Primeng, this problem will be solved.
The current version as of this date where this issue is fixed is 17.16.0
